# Footnote numbering per-paragraph

Tags: numbering, footnotes, paragraphs

How can I produce this footnote numbering?

```
Paragraph 1: This is a text [footnote 1]. This is another [footnote 2].
Paragraph 2: I have seen in many books this usage of footnotes [footnote 1 for paragraph 2]. It is good. [footnote 2 for paragraph 2]

---------
1     [1] footnote1
      [2] footnote2

2     [1] footnote1 (for paragraph 2)
      [2] footnote2 (for paragraph 2)
```

Comment: You lost me with all the brackets.  Would it be sufficient to use 1.1 for first paragraph, first footnote, 1.2 for the second footnote in the first paragraph, and 2.1 for the first footnote in the second paragraph?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, first time with latex... I try this:

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{1}
\greektext
Είμαστε έτοιμοι;
\latintext
Text will be the first\footnoteB{a paragraph footnote}
text\footnoteB{another one}
text\footnoteB+{new paragraph}
text\footnoteB{another one}
text\footnoteB+{this is in a new paragraph}
\paragraph{2}
We are all good.\footnote{and yes.} \greektext Αυτά είναι πολύ καλά.\footnote{Είναι δύσκολο.}
\end{document}

Comment: Is it possible to have the paragraph numbering to the left of the footnotes to which are related to?

Comment: That would be a bit more ambitious.

Comment: @John2 I am interested in this too. Did you every get an answer that only gave the paragraph number once?

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that `\everypar` is used by many packages for their own purposes, and gets set to `\relax` frequently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\everypar{\refstepcounter{paragraph}\setcounter{footnote}{0}}% must be renewed frequently
This is text.\footnote{first paragraph, first footnote}
This is more text.\footnote{first paragraph, second footnote}

This is a new paragraph.\footnote{second paragraph, first footnote}
This is more text.\footnote{second paragraph, second footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image: small page]